# rectifiable fields

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, vector-fields

Let answer the two questions

- Is every smooth direction field in the plane is **globally** rectifiable ?

No, if the integral curves are circles, it would imply that circles are topologically equivalent to lines ?

- Consider the field of planes given by the one form : $y\,dx + dz = 0$.
  Why there is no surface tangent to the planes of this field ?

At a point $(a,b,c)$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$,  the equation of the plane of the given field is : $bx + z=0$. And ?

Comment: For the latter, you need to look up the Frobenius Theorem.

Comment: $X=(0,1,0)$ and $Y=(1,0,-y)$ span the distribution defined by the family of plans: $D=span(X,Y)$.
Frobenius theorem tells us: if such surface exists then $[X,Y] \in D$.

We have $[X,Y] = (0,0,1)\notin D$ so no such surface exists ?

Comment: You are off by a sign, but, yes, that's the correct argument!